# How to create a CiviMember 'Members only' area

Tags: civimember, drupal-9

I have a requirement to create a specific 'Download' area for certain Civi memberships.  We are using Drupal 9 with latest CiviCRM (5.66)

The usecase is that members can login and get a tab or some sort of link to a controlled area on the website where they can download various digital assets aimed valid for that particular membership.

I would have thought this was a fairly common requirement but looking through the Extensions directory, nothing is obvious.

Drupal has a Group module that may well fit the bill.  So just wondering if anyone has implemented a solution along thesee lines as I am trying to get my head around the design of this.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that works kind of out of the box is a built in dashboard for user who are logged in (/civicrm/user?reset=1). You can configure what to show ther under /civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/display?reset=1 - some features such as downlaoding a receipt for a contribution may be available, too.

Beyond that, options to configure, customize and style this page are very limited to my knowledge - the whole feature seems a bit like from "the old CiviCRM world".

You could also use the [(somewhat) core features](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/integration/drupal/) of Drupal Group and Member Synch as well as the integration features of Drupal views and Drupal Webforms to build something custom.

As those "extended core integration features" sometimes turned out to be a bit limited as well for us, we have recently built self service portals, member login areas etc. with the ever growing toolbox of CiviCRM Extensions and Drupal modules. Unfortunately many of them are not well documented yet but I am going to list a few that may be of interest:

**[Remote Tools](https://github.com/systopia/de.systopia.remotetools):** Can assign a "Remote ID" that connects a Drupal User and teh CiviCRM contaact. May allow to show only the logged ind Users, Events, data, memberships etc.

**[CMRF/Drupal Webform/CiviCRM Formprocessor](https://docs.civicrm.org/formprocessor/en/latest/sign-up-newsletter/):** Allows to create flexible webforms that sends data and files to a CiviCRM-Formprocessor (allowing for very flexible configurable processing options).

**Drupal Views & CMRF:** Allows to create views (also views filtered on relevant data for the currently logged in user e.g. only the logged in Users' Data). The source for the view can be a CiviCRM API which allows for very flexible configurations.

**[Self Service Extension](https://github.com/systopia/de.systopia.selfservice):** Can send out a hashed/personalized link to a form that will allow users to change their own data without logging in.

**[The Extended Contact Matcher](https://docs.civicrm.org/xcm/en/latest/):** Extension that provides very flexible configuration for Matching and updating contacts via the API (required for some of the other extensions listed here).

**[Remote Events:](https://docs.civicrm.org/remoteevent/en/latest/)** Let's you configure events in CiviCRM, display/use that information in other remote systems and submit registrations for those events back to CiviCRM.

This list could probably go on for quite a bit. To sum up: You can do amazing stuff with those/other extensions as well as genereal CiviCRM Features. However, unless you have a rather simple usecase in mind, designing, setting it up etc. will require a lot of time and effort, particularly when doing it for the first time. Particularly providing downloads for "various digital assets" may require some work.

If you elaborate on your requirements a bit more I may be able to suggest a rough setup which is a bit more specific.

Comment: Hi Fabian - that is great, thank you.  Plenty to research there.  Over the next few months I'll try and build an MVP that gives the users what I 'think' they are asking for and if OK will document it here.  My understanding is that the primary driver is to control access to the download of digital assets, but as we all know, what we think users want rarely survives the initial demo of a working prototype :0)